# How to send a block of text with various indent of the text?

Tags: autohotkey

How can I send a text with AutoHotKey that results text output as below ?

```
Alfa
  Bravo
    Charlie
Delta
```

I have tried to use this operation:

```
text =
(
Alfa
  Bravo
    Charlie
Delta
)
Send % text
Return
```

But that returns this text:

```
Alfa
  Bravo
      Charlie
      Delta
```

So it looks like the indentation spaces accumulate, thus the indentation becomes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution in this case is the use of the clipboard:

```
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll  ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
clipboard := ""            ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
clipboard =                ; copy this text:
(
Alfa
  Bravo
    Charlie
Delta
)
ClipWait, 1                   ; wait for the clipboard to contain data. 
If (!ErrorLevel)              ; If NOT ErrorLevel ClipWait found data on the clipboard
    Send, ^v                  ; paste the text
Sleep, 300                    ; don't change the clipboard while pasting! (Sleep > 0)
clipboard := ClipSaved        ; restore original clipboard
VarSetCapacity(ClipSaved, 0)  ; free the memory
return
```

If you often have to send such a complex or long text, you can create a function, for not repeating the whole code every time:

```
my_text =
(
Alfa
  Bravo
    Charlie
Delta
)
Send(my_text)
return

Send(text){
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
    clipboard := ""
    clipboard := text
    ClipWait, 1
    If (!ErrorLevel)
        Send, ^v        
    Sleep, 300
    clipboard := ClipSaved
    VarSetCapacity(ClipSaved, 0)
}
```

See also [JoinString](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Scripts.htm#Join).